# asp.net duplicate localhost url path

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I hope you can help me with a small problem i been trying to solve. Using C#, I built a ASP.NET website that have 4 pages. (Home | Configuration| Blah | Contact) where Configuration menu has sub menu - config1, config2 like this:

**Menu:**

Home
Configuration :
  - config1
  - config2
Blah 
Contact

Home page directory : index.aspx

Configuration page directory : pages/config1.aspx and pages/config2.aspx

What I have an issue is: when I click pages/config1.aspx, go to the right page, and then on this same page I click pages/config2.aspx, a problem starts - duplicate pages/pages/config2.aspx - got error message. How to solve this problem?

I have copied codes from stackoverflow which seems not helpful. The solution like this below:

In MasterPage Page_Load:

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
// http://localhost:1302/TESTERS/Default6.aspx

string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
// /TESTERS/Default6.aspx

string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
// localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a relative anchor instead of an absolute one. Try changing

```
<a href="pages/pages.config2.aspx">link</a>
```

to

```
<a href="/pages/pages.config2.aspx">link</a>
```

Comment: <li><a href="/pages/config2.aspx">config 2</a></li> got error path like this: http://localhost:xxxx/pages/vendors.aspx. should be http://localhost:xxxxx/testWeb/pages/vendors.aspx

Answer (score 0):

or even this will work

```
<a href="~/pages/pages.config2.aspx">link</a>
```

Comment: <a href="~/pages/config2.aspx">config 2</a> got error : http://localhost:xxxxx/testWeb/~/pages/vendors.aspx

Comment: why there is a dot  ~/pages/pages.config2.aspx? this is not working

Answer (score 0):

you can in masterpage get your url with this code:

```
string test = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Substring(1, Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Length - 1);
```

and you can response your pages with this codes:

```
<a href="../config2.aspx">link</a>
```